# React how to run 2 function async simultaneously using metamask?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I woudlike to run 2 pending in my metamask wallet : stake then harvest :

```
const [pendingTx, setPendingTx] = useState(false)
const {onReward} = useHarvest(pid)
const {onStake} = useStake(3)

<Button
                        disabled={rawEarningsBalance === 0 || pendingTx}
                        size='sm'
                        variant='secondary'
                        marginBottom='15px'
                        onClick={async () => {
                            setPendingTx(true)
                            await onStake(rawEarningsBalance.toString())
                            await onReward()
                            setPendingTx(false)
                        }
                        }
                    >
                        {TranslateString(999, 'Pack it')}
                    </Button>
```

Actually when I run it my first function run (`await onStake`) but after my wallet metamask don't show me to confirm harvest. It show me unauthorized so I need to click on it to show the pending popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got your problem...
If you want to run `onStake` in parallel with `onReward` you can not use `await` in front of each because then it waits for this specific promise to complete.
You can instead add all your promises which should run in parallel to a `Promise.all` and `await` on this multi-promise object.

```
onClick={async () => {
    setPendingTx(true)
    await Promise.all([
        onStake(rawEarningsBalance.toString()),
        onReward()
    ]);
    setPendingTx(false)
}
```